# Можно ли перенести сайт с html на WordPress?

Tags: html, wordpress

Если страниц около 4к? это реально или нет?

Comment: Можно. В чём вы видите проблему?

Comment: как перенести такой обьем страниц? По одной штуке переноситЬ? или есть быстрый способ

Comment: Написать парсер, который считывает html и создаёт страницы в WP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе, можно. Есть плагины WP, позволяющие это сделать - htmlImport2, например (https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-html-pages/).
Конвертировать дизайн в тему можно здесь (https://www.themematcher.com/)